# upgrade SP2007 -> 2010. Missing service application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade

I did SP 2007 SP3 in-line upgrade to SP 2010 (enterprise licence). Upgrade passed ok except the fact that upgrade didn't create all service applications. As this is expected thing, i thought that I would be able later to create them via "Central Administration -> Manage Service Application" but for some reason I can only create BDC, PerfPoint and User Profile service apps. Any other apps like Managed Metadata, Office based, Search, ... are not even listed in apps repository.

As I said licence is enterprise, Services are enabled via SP Configuration Wizard and with both accounts, SPService and my(which is SpFarm + local admin) i get same response..

Please, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Central Admin > System Settings > Manage Services on Server and ensure the services are running for the service applications.

Comment: Missing services are not even listed (on your link). I assume that i should try install them via Powershell (by force) but it's weird that this is impossible via CA.